how to provide aws glue job parameters via terraform?
I am setting up an glue job in aws via terraform (sample below ) . based on the docs here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-glue-arguments.html, any additional package needed for the glue job can be passed via --additional-python-modules under job parameter reference, but how do i pass this information when setting up a job via terraform like below .
resource "aws_glue_job" "example" {
  name     = "example job"
  role_arn = aws_iam_role.example.arn
  number_of_workers=4

  command {
    name            = "gluestreaming"
    script_location = "s3://${aws_s3_bucket.test.data}/temp.script"
  }
  # ... other configuration ...

  default_arguments = {
    # ... potentially other arguments ...
    "--continuous-log-logGroup"          = aws_cloudwatch_log_group.example.name
    "--enable-continuous-cloudwatch-log" = "true"
    "--enable-continuous-log-filter"     = "true"
    "--enable-metrics"                   = ""
  }
}


You need to add it to your default_arguments block. Make sure the packages you specify are separated by ,.
Here's how you can do it:
  default_arguments = {
    # ... potentially other arguments ...
    "--continuous-log-logGroup"          = aws_cloudwatch_log_group.example.name
    "--enable-continuous-cloudwatch-log" = "true"
    "--enable-continuous-log-filter"     = "true"
    "--enable-metrics"                   = ""
    "--additional-python-modules"        = "package1==1.0.0,pacakge2"
  }
}

It's optional to use a version for the packages, but usually it's the better practice to include that.
